# Is there a way to replace the Android system file manager with a third-party file manager?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, file-system, file-management, system-apps

I'm using an OnePlus 3 with Android 6 (Marshmallow). For me the standard Android system file manager that opens when you want to send a photo or video via WhatsApp is just horrible.
It's slow and you have to click several times to reach your desired folder.

So, is there a way to make a third-party file manager (SolidExplorer for me) open instead of the system file manager? I know I can open the file manager from the system file manager (bottom of the sidebar) but I would like to skip this two clicks.

Does anyone has a clue on how to achieve this?